# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 is not showing opening braces on editor C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using visual studio 2010 Ultimate for developing C# application. My editor is not showing the opening braces in the funcion call.
for eg.

```
var file = new StreamReader**(**fileName);
```

In this function its opening braces although it is present when I paste it. It was working fine earlier. I have restore the editor settings. I didnt find any help on net for the same nor a helpline for visual tudio on internet. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's with the `**`? and that doesn't look like a function to me..

Comment: This is definitely a good candidate for a screen shot to show the problem. Also, I believe you mean paranthesis `(` not braces `{`

Comment: The `**`s are to show what he means by opening braces.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, in my case it was an studio plugin - try to start VS with the safe mode switch and take a look if the error still appears...
"devenv.exe /SafeMode"

%Program Files(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /SafeMode

Comment: Eric I am seeing this in VS editor var file = new StreamReader fileName);

Cadbury: safe mode option didnt worked for me.

Comment: I figured out, My font file got corrupted and it was not working for that font only. After chaging the font its working fine.